# Tuples, list and Dictionaries code to print rows and columns

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to make a little code that based on tuples, lists and dictionaries. I have the code below  but I has the following errors:

1. It only takes the values of "discount and store_product" but I need it  to also consider the discount.
2. When it prints, It prints in the following form.

   ```
   {'1': 'Tango', '2': 'Ice cream', '3': 'Gum rolls', '4': 'Wet Napkins', '5': 'Catfood', '6': 'DoogFood'} ['none', 'none', 'none', '10%', '5%', '5%']

   {'T': ['1'], 'a': ['1', '2', '4', '5'], 'n': ['1', '4'], 'g': ['1', '6'], 'o': ['1', '3', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6'], 'I': ['2'], 'c': ['2', '2'], 'e': ['2', '2', '4'], ' ': ['2', '3', '4'], 'r': ['2', '3'], 'm': ['2', '3'], 'G': ['3'], 'u': ['3'], 'l': ['3', '3'], 's': ['3', '4'], 'W': ['4'], 't': ['4', '5'], 'N': ['4'], 'p': ['4'], 'k': ['4'], 'i': ['4'], 'C': ['5'], 'f': ['5'], 'd': ['5', '6'], 'D': ['6'], 'F': ['6']}
   ```
3. IGNORE THE *INVERT* PORTION OF THE CODE. I am experimenting with that part of python but if you have any recommendations to make it better, I want to hear it.

I want the code to print like this.

```
1 Tango .40 none
2 Ice cream .25 none   **OR SIMILAR FORM**
3 Gum rolls .50 none.
```

Every time I try adding the price, it gives me an error message saying:
`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'`

Can someone point out the right direction to fix this with a brief description, please.

```
discount = ["none", "none", "none", "10%", "5%", "5%"]
price = float((.40, 0.25, .50, 3.75, .68, .85))
store_product = {
    "1": "Tango",
    "2": "Ice cream",
    "3": "Gum rolls",
    "4": "Wet Napkins",
    "5": "Catfood",
    "6": "DoogFood",
}


print(store_product, price, discount)
print("")


def invert(d):
  inverse = dict()
  for key in d:
    val = d[key]
    for item in val:
      if item not in inverse:
        inverse[item] = [key]
      else:
        inverse[item].append(key)
  return inverse 


inverted_product = invert(store_product)
print(inverted_product)
```

Is it even possible to do something like that or I am overthinking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print `discount`, `price` and `store_product` together, you can do:

```py
discount = ["none", "none", "none", "10%", "5%", "5%"]
price = (0.40, 0.25, 0.50, 3.75, 0.68, 0.85)
store_product = {
    "1": "Tango",
    "2": "Ice cream",
    "3": "Gum rolls",
    "4": "Wet Napkins",
    "5": "Catfood",
    "6": "DoogFood",
}

for k, v in store_product.items():
    k = int(k)
    print(v, price[k - 1], discount[k - 1])
```

Prints:

```
Tango 0.4 none
Ice cream 0.25 none
Gum rolls 0.5 none
Wet Napkins 3.75 10%
Catfood 0.68 5%
DoogFood 0.85 5%
```